# For the Vim editor, how do I map a function key in .vimrc on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, vim

I'm trying to map f11 to a command within vim, with a line in .vimrc such as:

```
map <F11> :exe '!ctags -R --python-kinds=-i -f ./tags ' . shellescape(system('python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"'))<CR>
```

But if you hit F11 it just turns up the volume.  Is it possible to remap keys that have
OS-wide functions in OSX?

I don't want to remap any more commonly used key here because regenerating tags takes awhile.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options that I know of:

1) Enable the regular use of the function keys, ie. f1 - f12 no longer executes the OSX specific command such as decrease volume.  Instead you will have to hold the `fn` key press the `f` key.  I have this set up on my computer and I've successfully mapped the function keys in Vim / MacVim.  To do this go to `System preferences --> Keyboard` and check of the `Use all F1, F2,...`

2) Use `fn` + `F11` to execute the command.

Comment: Option 2 does not work (under OSX Lion at least): fn + F11 executes the MacOS "show desktop", it doesn't execute the mapped command.

Comment: But you can use preferences to disable F11 = show desktop and then fn + F11 works.

Comment: The corresponding setting is in the mission control section of system preferences.

Answer (score 0):

6 years later...

Check out https://github.com/Pyroh/Fluor/releases

It allows you to change the behavior of the function keys based on the app that is currently active.